# getting reference to the clicked button inside an ajax event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a way to get a reference to the caller button/link, inside an ajax event. 
for example:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();

 function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}
```

In the reqListener function, to get the button id/class etc.. (I'm talking about cases when isTrusted=true)

Below you can find the load event, as it appears in console. The only reference is to the xhr object itself:

[image]

Comment: Where is your `click` listener?

Comment: I don't have access to it. I'm writing a '3rd party library', and my script will be added to the page, same as google analytics script.

Comment: Then there's probably nothing you can do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing something you shouldn't be doing.

For such cases, you should usually use some (bad) workaround unless you can get the access to the code that's executing the XHR request.

Some workarounds you can consider:

1. Look at the `document.activeElement` hoping the link/button didn't lose the focus so fast.
2. Add a global event listener for all `a`, `input[type=button]`, `button` onclick events and register the last clicked element somewhere on the root element (`window` in a webpage). This depends if you're using some 3rd party library and you should consider the case of new elements being added to the DOM after your event registration finished.

Comment: @LiorGoldemberg That's an *extremely* fragile solution, use with care.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, can you elaborate? do you have an experience with that? what went wrong?

Comment: `document.activeElement` is a reference to the currently active element. It is not hard to imagine a case where the active element happens to not be the button you are interested in, but any other element on the page. It is, essentially, relying on a global variable to be in the correct configuration for your function to work, which is not a 100% solid thing to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a handler for the xhr call with a reference to the button in it's closure. something like this might help:
(the get doesn't work in the snippet due to cors)

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  console.log('clicked')
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.onload = console.log;//getReqListener(e.target);
  oReq.open("GET", "https://www.example.com/example.txt");
  oReq.send();

}

function getReqListener(target) {
  console.log('getreq')
  return function(data) {
    console.log('fetched');
    console.log(target.text)
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the button is exposed to you in a closure, there's no way for you to get it, it is out of scope.

You are basically asking

```
function foo(cb) {
  const btn = 'You can\'t get me!';
  cb();
}

foo(() => { /* How can I get the value of btn here? */ });
```

That's not possible.